Singular integral, Navier-Stokes equations.
Given $f \in L^2((0,T))$, I would like to prove that
$$
  \int_0^t (t-s)^{-\frac{1}{2}}|f(s)|ds
  $$
is in $L^2((0,T))$ as well. Is it true? What seems difficult to me is that it does not look like as a typical Calderón-Zygmund kernel because you don't have both sides of singularity, so the cancellation does not happen. Also, the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality does not look like to hold with this choice of $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}, p=q=2$.
To have some context of how it came out: I am doing some estimates on Navier-Stokes equation in the Duhamel/mild formulation. Given the forcing term $f \in L^2( (0,T), H^2(\mathbb{R}^3))$, I would like to bound
$$
  \int_0^t e^{(t-s)\Delta}f(x,s)ds
  $$
in norm $L^2( (0,T), H^3(\mathbb{R}^3))$, where $e^{(t-s)\Delta}f(x,s)$ is the standard heat convolution in. Putting the $H^3$ norm inside the integral and giving one derivative in $x$ to the heat kernel and two to $f$, it boils down to bound
$$
  \int_0^t (t-s)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\|f(\cdot,s)\|_{H^2}ds
$$
in $L^2((0,T))$. This is of the form above.

The kind of tool you are looking for is called $\mathrm{L}^q$-maximal regularity, this will solve your problem with only few lines. The problem of $\mathrm{L}^q$-maximal regularity belongs to the realm of vector-valued Calderón-Zygmund Theory and Harmonic Analysis.
Theorem ($\mathrm{L}^q$-maximal regularity for the Laplacian) Let
$p,q\in(1,+\infty)$ , $T\in(0,+\infty]$. Let $f\in\mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$. Then, the equation
\begin{align}\tag{HE}\label{HE}
    \left\{\begin{array}{rl}
            \partial_t u(t) -\Delta u(t)  =& f(t) \,\text{, } 0<t<T \text{, }\\
            u(0) =& 0.
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{align}
admits a unique mild solution $u\in\mathrm{C}^0([0,T];\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$  given by the Duhamel formula
\begin{align*}
u(t)=\int_{0}^{t} e^{(t-s)\Delta}f(s,\cdot)\mathrm{~d}s,\quad t\in[0,T],
\end{align*}
and is such that $\partial_t u,\Delta u\in \mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$ with the estimate
\begin{align*}\tag{$\text{MR}_{q}(\mathrm{L}^p)$}\label{MRqLp}
\lVert \partial_t u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))} + \lVert \Delta u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))} \leqslant C_{p,q,n} \lVert f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))}.
\end{align*}
Where $C_{p,q,n}$ is depending only on $p,q,n$ but not on $u$ and $T$.
If moreover $T<+\infty$, we also have $u\in\mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$ with an estimate
\begin{align*}
\lVert u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))}\leqslant C_{p,q,n}'\cdot T \lVert f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^q(0,T;\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n))}.
\end{align*}
Solution to the problem.
Goal: Since one has the equivalence of norms
\begin{align*}
\lVert w\rVert_{\mathrm{H}^3(\mathbb{R}^n)}\sim_{n}\lVert w\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} + \lVert \nabla^3 w\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)},
\end{align*}
we aim to show
\begin{align*}
\lVert u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}\leqslant C_{n}'\cdot T \lVert f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))},\quad\text{ and }\quad\lVert \nabla^3 u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))} \leqslant C_{n} \lVert \nabla f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}.
\end{align*}
Taking the sum will give us the desired estimate
\begin{align*}
\lVert  u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{H}^3(\mathbb{R}^n))}  &\leqslant {C''_{n,T}}\lVert  f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{H}^1(\mathbb{R}^n))}\leqslant  {C''_{n,T}} \lVert f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}.
\end{align*}
Proof: Let $f\in\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))\subset \mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$, since $T<+\infty$ by the previous Theorem, one obtains
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{MR2}
\lVert \nabla^2 u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}=\lVert \Delta u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))} \leqslant C_{n} \lVert f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))},
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{MR22}
\lVert u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}\leqslant C_{n}'\cdot T \lVert f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}.
\end{align}
Now, using the Fourier transform in the space variable, one may see that, for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, one can commute the space derivatives
\begin{align*}
\partial_{x_k}u(t)=\int_{0}^{t} e^{(t-s)\Delta}[\partial_{x_k}f](s,\cdot)\mathrm{~d}s,\quad t\in[0,T].
\end{align*}
Since $\partial_{x_k}f\in\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$, we can apply \eqref{MR2} replacing $f$ by $\nabla f$, in order to obtain
\begin{align*}\tag{3}\label{MR23}
\lVert \nabla^3 u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))} = \lVert \nabla^2(\nabla u)\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}= \lVert \Delta(\nabla u)\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}  \leqslant C_{n} \lVert \nabla f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}.
\end{align*}
From there, summing \eqref{MR2} and \eqref{MR23} yields
\begin{align*}
\lVert  u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}^2+\lVert \nabla^3 u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}^2  &\leqslant ({C'_{n}}^2\cdot T^2+ C_{n}^2)(\lVert  f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}^2+ \lVert \nabla f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}^2),
\end{align*}
so that, by equivalence of norms over $\mathrm{H}^3$, finally,
\begin{align*}
\lVert  u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{H}^3(\mathbb{R}^n))}  &\leqslant {C''_{n,T}}\lVert  f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{H}^1(\mathbb{R}^n))}\leqslant{C''_{n,T}}  \lVert f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(0,T;\mathrm{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))}.
\end{align*}$\square$
P.S.: In a future edit, I will add some comments and a simple proof in the case $p=q=2$, giving the references about more general results allowing to prove the cases where $p,q\neq2$.
